# How to disable mouse in vim window when it's enabled by "set mouse = a"?

Tags: macos, vim, set, mouse

Hi: I'm using vim and I've `set mouse=a` in my .vimrc, so upon startup, vim supports mouse cursor. But some times I need to copy text from terminal, so I need to shut down mouse support in vim. I tried `set mouse=c` but the mouse still works in my mac terminal.

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to shutdown your mouse at all, can't you paste it with your keyboard (it would be Shift+insert in *unix and i think command+v in osx) ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try

`:set mouse-=a`

The `-=` removes any active option.

Comment: You can also use `:set mouse=` which will remove all of the current options.

Comment: :set mouse! will also works , any "!"(bang) after a command ,deactivates it .

Comment: Neither `:set mouse-=a` nor `:set mouse!` work for me in my global vimrc :( Mouse-selecting still switches to visual mode.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368734/how-should-i-have-handled-this-rejected-edit Your edit rejection is discuss on meta. It is better if you can add a reply why you rejected it. :-)

Comment: @nyov I had the same. Check for vim config script in */usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim*

Answer (score 12):

If you wanna disable the mouse in your global config (`/etc/vimrc`), just add this:

```
set mouse=
set ttymouse=
```

Comment: For me it works globally putting directives in `/etc/vim/vimrc` file.